# Splitting expression by regular expressions (PHP)

Tags: php, regex

I want to split string: "33A/5" on parts "33", "A", "5".

Is in php possibility to write some regex as: `"/^(\d+) (\D) \/? (\d+)/"`, where expressions in brackets `( exp )` become separate parts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) like this:

```
preg_match("/^(\d+) (\D+) \/? (\d+)/x", $text, $match);
```

`$match` will be an array with the separate matches.

The `x` modifier is to ignore spaces in the regex; otherwise, don't put the spaces:

```
preg_match("/^(\d+)(\D+)\/?(\d+)/", $text, $match);
```

Comment: Hm, it's works (I used regexp "/^(\d+)(\D)\/?(\d+)/"). But I have one problem, result is looking as: Array ([0] => 33A/5; [1] => 33; [2] => A; [3] => 5). First element is excess (I know, that I can just ignore him, but it's not clear). :(

Comment: There's no problem. See in the docs: `$matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern`. So just start with the second element.

Comment: You need to use `$match[1], $match[2], $match[3]`, `$match[0]` is the entire string here.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, using a single `preg_split` call, too:

```
$chunks = preg_split(
    '/(\d+|[^\/\d]+)\/?/',
    '33A/5',
    -1,
    PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE |
    PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY
);
var_dump($chunks);
```

dumps:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "33"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "A"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "5"
}
```

[as shown here](http://codepad.org/9rmTLRQA)

This approach works much the same [as this answer]. The expression matches everything, except for the `/`, effectively turning the data you want into the delimiters. Because we *want* the delimiters, you have to use the `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` constant.
Of course, as they are the delimiters, it'll split the string on those substrings, and since there's nothing between the delimiters, you'll end up with an empty value for each *split*-point, as it were. That's why I'm also using the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` constant, using the bitwise `|` operator

The expression itself:

- `(`: begin matching group
- `\d+` matches one or more digits, greedy -> in group!
- `|`: or, if the `\d+` can't be matched, use:
- `[^\/\d]+`: greedy match of any char that isn't a `/` or a digit -> in group
- `)\/?`: Close group, match *optional* `/`, outside of group => so it's not matched as part of the captured delimiter

Comment: Thanks you. I will remember this way too.